# Package Connected App

Tags: managed-package, connected-apps

My app uses the Salesforce API and a managed package. Inside of the package, I have a connected app using OAuth and the Rest API. When the package has been installed, are users redirected to the call back URL? I need the package to be installed and users to pair our app with Salesforce. Many apps I viewed have no packages. Users just install the app through their website. Should this be the approach that I take?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Packaging a Connected App is a legacy feature that was initially required in order to use them in other orgs. This is no longer a requirement, as the first time it is used in an org, it's automatically "installed" so that administrators can configure it. You don't even *need* a managed package at all any more for this purpose, as the Client ID that you provide during the authentication flow is sufficient enough to identify your app, display the logo, etc. The callback URL *must match* the callback URL provided by the calling app, or a security error will prevent the redirect.

Comment: Was looking at the docs on https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_connected_app.htm which suggests the Connected App must be packaged in a 1GP then referenced in the 2GP project. Does this still apply? We have an Aura Canvas App that requires the Connected App. The Canvas Lifecycle class is specified in the Connected App. Wondering if our use case still requires the Connected App in the 1GP. Also, by Client ID, do you mean the Connected App's Consumer Key?