# Second-generation Managed Package with dependency on first-generation Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, 2gp, 1gp-package

Creating a second-generation Managed Package (2GP) that has a dependency on a released first-generation Managed Package (1GP).

This is what I want the version progression for the package **Connector for Salesforce** to be:

| Version Name | Version Number | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aurora 2023 | 2.1.0.7 | Last release of first-generation managed package |
| Aurora 2023.2 | 2.1.1.1 | First release of second-generation managed package |

Got the information about my 1GP (**namespace** = xyzzy) from its **Packaging and Namespace Org** with:

```bash
sfdx force:package1:version:list -u username@company.1gp
```

| MetadataPackageVersionId | MetadataPackageId | Name | Version | ReleaseState | BuildNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04t... | 033.. | Aurora 2023 | 2.1.0 | Released | 7 |

On my **Dev Hub** (username@company.devhub), I linked my namespace (with username@company.1gp) then created a 2GP like this:

```bash
sfdx force:package:create --name "Connector for Salesforce" --packagetype Managed --path force-app/
```

| NAME | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| Package Id | 0Ho... |

Now for the sfdx-project.json...

```json
{
  "namespace": "xyzzy",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "56.0",
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "default": true,
      "package": "Connector for Salesforce",
      "path": "force-app",
      "versionName": "Aurora 2023.2",
      "versionNumber": "2.1.1.NEXT",
      "definitionFile": "config/project-scratch-def.json",
      "dependencies": [
        {
          "package": "Connector for Salesforce (1GP)@2.1.0.7"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "packageAliases": {
    "Connector for Salesforce": "0Ho...",
    "Connector for Salesforce (1GP)@2.1.0.7": "04t...",
    "Connector for Salesforce (1GP)": "033..."
  }
}
```

When I run

```bash
sfdx force:package:beta:version:create -p 0Ho... --installationkeybypass -b next
```

After recommendations from @Phil W below, the error is now...

> ERROR running force:package:version:create:  Can’t create patch
> version. Log a case in the Salesforce Partner Community and request
> that patch versioning be enabled in the org where you created the
> namespace for this package.

UPDATE: This error occurred because I was trying to make the first version of my second-generation managed package 2.1.0.NEXT instead of 1.0.0.NEXT. The reason I chose that version was to create continuity with my 1GP. Patch versioning was not needed. The error message from it was erroneous (and unhelpful).

Comment: I'm confused. Is Aurora the 1GP and you're trying to make it depend on the Connector 2GP? That seems to be what you've done in the `sfdx-project.json` comparing this with the detail you provided above that. If this is what you've done then you cannot; a 1GP cannot depend on a 2GP. If that's not what you've done I would say that you have the structure the wrong way round in the `sfdx-project.json`...

Comment: Cleaned up my question to make it clearer and implement some of your recommendations below.

Comment: Do you really still have a question now you "cleaned up" the `sfdx-project.json`? What's still going wrong?

Comment: Ah, patch versioning. Have you had your package go through security review and pass? Only then can you have patching enabled...

Comment: The plan was to submit the 2GP package for the security review. We're in the process of becoming an ISV Partner and waiting on Salesforce legal's review. Wanted to get everything working using 2GP so the review is based on the latest/greatest.

Comment: You cannot have patch versioning until after security review is passed for both 1GP and 2GP.

Are you not going to just replace your 1GP with a 2GP then?

Comment: Yeah - I want the 2GP to just replace the 1GP. The 1GP only exists for housing the Connected Apps as they cannot be created in a 2GP - only referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "Aurora" is your 1GP and it is to be a dependency for your 2GP "Connector for Salesforce", your `sfdx-project.json` for your 2GP should be more like:

```
{
  "namespace": "xyzzy",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "56.0",
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "default": true,
      "package": "Connector for Salesforce",
      "path": "force-app",
      "versionName": "Connector for Salesforce 2.1.1",
      "versionNumber": "2.1.1.NEXT",
      "definitionFile": "config/project-scratch-def.json",
      "dependencies": [
        {
          "package": "Aurora@2.1.0.7"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "packageAliases": {
    "Aurora@2.1.0.7": "04t..."
  }
}
```

You need to have the 2GP depend on the 1GP. I've used a package alias here to make that dependency more readable.

Comment: Thanks Phil. Aurora is the version name but your example is helpful. Let me give this a try. I will also update my question above and post results.

Comment: Naming the 1GP and 2GP packages more-or-less the same is a bit strange.

Comment: Regarding the naming... no one has the 1GP (only installed once for testing on a Dev org). The only reason it was created in the first place was because Connected Apps have to be created in a 1GP otherwise, I would have started with 2GP and never had this dependency (frustrating).

Comment: Do you really need a packaged Connected App? Is it a must that every install gets a different client ID/secret? Or could you use a shared Connected App created on your "Partner Business Org" (PBO; that's the CRM/production org for ISVs)? We took this latter approach. No need to package it, no need for 1GP.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/134357/package-connected-app) and [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/367055/packaging-connected-app-in-2gp-package-cli-says-package-is-deleted) for some more detail.

Comment: Based on those links, it looks like we won't have any need for the 1GP. We'll just need the PBO once we are approved as an ISV Partner. Can a PBO trial be converted to a PBO once we are approved? If so, I'll open a ticket with Salesforce.

Comment: I can't answer that last question; I joined my company after the PBO was in place. Sorry.

Comment: Phil W - You mentioned your Connected App was created in your PBO but not in a package. From my understanding, in my 2GP project, the ".connectedApp-meta.xml" file's developerName field should reference the namespace and name of the Connected App. Is your PBO a namespace org? My understanding is that the PBO is normally the org to make the Dev Hub but then it cannot be a namespace org. Curious how your company structured this.

Comment: You do not need to put the Connected App metadata in your package in order to use the connected app on the PBO (which has no namespace and is the DevHub).

Comment: In our Aura Component Bundle, the force:canvasApp has a developerName attribute that's supposed to be the name of the Connected App. If the Connected App is not referenced anywhere in the 2GP package, how will we connect to our customer's orgs to sync data (we use the JWT Bearer OAuth flow)?

Comment: I haven't used canvasApp so cannot tell you how to solve this directly.

Comment: Oh ok... the Salesforce docs really push the idea that you have to put the Connected Apps into a 1GP to reference them from an Aura Component Bundle in a 2GP... https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_connected_app.htm

Comment: I have reached out to a Salesforce packaging expert to ask their advice. They will comment here later, with luck...

Comment: Really appreciate the help Phil W!